# How to bind jquery .text() to HTML tag?

Tags: jquery

I have one value like ** `var result=$('result').text();` ** I want to put this result .value to html tag. example: **`var htmltag="<strong></strong>";`** I want to get output is **`<strong>result</strong>` ** . Note that :

http://jsfiddle.net/v142v3xq/3/

Comment: why not `var htmltag="<strong>"+result+"</strong>";`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Because *ick*. What if result is "any arbitrary data"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not using a proper template system, I prefer to "create elements first" and then fill in *dynamic* attributes (or *dynamic* text content) as needed.

Using jQuery this might look like:

```
var $elm = $("<strong/>").text(result);
// And add new element as appropriate
$target.append($elm);
```

Note that `text(val)` returns the same object as the receiver, which is very handy, so the code can be expanded as:

```
var $elm = $("<strong/>");  // create STRONG element, add to new jQ object
$elm.text(result);          // set text of all elements (only STRONG here)
```

Here is [a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/v142v3xq/).

Comment: The jsfiddle posted in that comment has a trivial mistake with the selector ([here is a correction](http://jsfiddle.net/v142v3xq/4/)) so the value read is "" - `$("#result")` selects on the ID, but `$(".result")` select on the Class.

Comment: I tried to put result in text box. It is not showing well in textbox.: http://jsfiddle.net/v142v3xq/7/

Comment: @user1381501: `<input>` elements don’t support rich formatting. If you want to bold the whole thing, use CSS; otherwise, you may have to go for `contentEditable`, which is not easy to get right.

Comment: @minitech: I want to change partially in input box. How should I use CSS?http://jsfiddle.net/v142v3xq/9/

Answer (score 2):

Use [JQuery wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

```
$('result').wrap("<strong></strong>");
```

But using the selector 'result' is probably not what you want...this will select the element with the result **id**.

```
$('#result').wrap("<strong></strong>");
```